# Building a connect 4 game, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to remove the classes that represent users moves on reset

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am building a connect 4 game using JavaScript, right now users can play the game as expected and the program checks for the winner and stops the game once player 1 or player 2 wins the game.
This part of the game seems to be working as expected: there are two players, represented by two different colors (in this case red and yellow) and the game goes from one color to another.
My issue is with restarting the game. I have a restart button, which resets the timer, but I can't figure out how to remove the red and yellow pieces from the game board.

More specifically, I think my issue is that I can't figure out how to remove a class from a div I created inside a function.

I created each tile inside the function I used to set up the game board:

```
function setGame() {
    board = [];
    currColumns = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
    
    for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        let row = []
        for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
            row.push(' ');
            let tile = document.createElement('div');
            tile.id = r.toString() + '-' + c.toString()
            tile.classList.add('tile');
            tile.addEventListener('click', setPiece);
            document.getElementById('board').append(tile);
            console.log(tile)
        }
        board.push(row)
    }
}
```

Then I used tile again to identify each individual tile and add the red or yellow color when the user clicks the board

```
function setPiece() {
    // if there is a winner, the function does nothing so pieces cannot be set
    if (gameOver) {
        return;
    }

    let coords = this.id.split('-');
    let r = parseInt(coords[0]);
    let c = parseInt(coords[1]);

    r = currColumns[c];
    if (r < 0) {
        return
    }

    board[r][c] = currentPlayer;
    let tile = document.getElementById(r.toString() + '-' + c.toString());
    // console.log(tile)
    if (currentPlayer == playerRed) {
        tile.classList.add('red-piece')
        clearInterval(intervalID)
        currentPlayer = playerYellow
    } else {
        tile.classList.add('yellow-piece')
        currentPlayer = playerRed
    }
    // setInterval(setTimer, 1000);

    r -= 1;
    // console.log(r)
    currColumns[c] = r;

    checkWinner()
}
```

Once a winner is found, the click event that allows users to add pieces is removed.
I have a restart button that will restart the timer and allow users to add pieces to the board, but what I can't figure out is how to remove the pieces from the board. I know that my board is made up of tiles, and that the filled in tiles have either a class of 'red-piece' or 'yellow-piece' but I can't figure out how to remove them.

Comment: Can you not just remove the `innerHtml` of `document.getElementById('board')` and then call `setGame()` again? Might as well add the removal of the `innerHtml` in the beginning of `setGame()`, so that you would just have to call the function.